# Angular: How to correctly set initial selected objects with @ng-select/ng-select module

Tags: angular

I created a custom component which I call to generate ng-select dropdowns.

However now it occured a problem which I'm not able to fix.
When I define initial selected value(s) it shows on the dropdown, but the checkbox stays selectable.
This might cause that the object ends up twice in the selected list.

[Please see my example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-example-5y3bib?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) | You'll see that person with id 2 is preselected, but checkbox is unchecked (and that same person can be selected another time, so it is twice in the list)

To create my Component I used the examples from ng-select:
[example](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/multiselect-checkbox) [example-source](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/tree/master/src/demo/app/examples/multi-checkbox-example)

How do I correctly map the initial selected objects, that the checkbox from selected objects is checked?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is the object set as initial value is new object by comparison it will not be found using _selected.indexOf(item)

If you change your code like below it will work

```
public selectedPersonList: Array<Person> = [this.personList[1]];
```

You can do Dynamically like below

```
replase _selected.indexOf(item) > -1
```

with

```
[ngModel]="isSelected(item)"
```

And defind the isSelect() like below

```
  isSelected(_item): boolean {
    return  this._selected && this._selected.findIndex(e => e.id == _item.id) > -1;
  }
```

Comment: Makes totally sense, thanks. Is there a more dynamic way to do this? The selectedPersonList is returned from server, so it might be empty or having mutliple preselected objects.

Comment: Check the edit now for dynamic way, instead of check use the predicate function